# How to Check if a contact on android phone book has whatsapp enabled?

Tags: android, android-contacts, whatsapp

For a given number from my address book, I need to look-up if the number has whatsapp enabled.
(The idea is to choose SMS/WhatsApp for initiating a text intent)

Lets say, I have two numbers under a contact, And I need to know which one has whatsapp enabled.

The "People" app on the Nexus 4 shows both contact numbers, 
And also a little below has a CONNECTIONS section, which shows only the WhatsApp possible contact.

Is there a way to look up(like how People app does) ?

Answer (score 16):

If you want to know if this contact has WhatsApp:

```
String[] projection = new String[] { RawContacts._ID };
String selection = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND account_type IN (?)";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "THE_CONTACT_DEVICE_ID", "com.whatsapp" };
Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
boolean hasWhatsApp = cursor.moveToNext();
if (hasWhatsApp){
    String rowContactId = cursor.getString(0);
}
```

And to find to which number of this contact has WhatsApp

```
projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.DATA3 };
selection = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? ";
selectionArgs = new String[] { "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.profile", rawContactId };
cursor = CallAppApplication.get().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, "1 LIMIT 1");
String phoneNumber = null;
if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    phoneNumber = cursor.getString(0);
}
```

Comment: What is "THE_CONTACT_DEVICE_ID"?

Comment: the contact_id of the user from the contacts table

Comment: how can we do it with phone number

Comment: Hi there, I have a cordova/capacitor app. Is there any chance I can implement this code in the Cordova app?

Answer (score 1):

Using @idog's method, I improved code to work easier. [contactID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.html#CONTACT_ID) is a string variable to be passed. If contact hasn't **WhatsApp** returns *null*, otherwise returns with **contactID** which has been passed as variable.

```
public String hasWhatsapp(String contactID) {
    String rowContactId = null;
    boolean hasWhatsApp;

    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID};
    String selection = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND account_type IN (?)";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{contactID, "com.whatsapp"};
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        hasWhatsApp = cursor.moveToNext();
        if (hasWhatsApp) {
            rowContactId = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return rowContactId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int hasWhatsApp(String contactID) {
        int whatsAppExists = 0;
        boolean hasWhatsApp;

        String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID};
        String selection = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND account_type IN (?)";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{contactID, "com.whatsapp"};
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            hasWhatsApp = cursor.moveToNext();
            if (hasWhatsApp) {
                whatsAppExists = 1;
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return whatsAppExists;
    }
```

Comment: this solution not working, please update the answer.