# Unable to identify WhatsApp contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, whatsapp, android-cursor, rawcontactid

I'm trying to write an Android program which can identify if a given contact number is associated with WhatsApp or not. I managed to find out if a particular contact name has WhatsApp account or not. How can I find out which contact corresponding to that contact name has WhatsApp? Currently I'm using the following code:

```
public void identifyWhatsappContact() {
    Cursor c = ctx.getContentResolver().query(
            RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY },
            RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ? AND " + StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " = ?",
            new String[] { "com.whatsapp", "John Doe" },
            null);

    ArrayList<String> myWhatsappContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
    int contactNameColumn = c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        myWhatsappContacts.add(c.getString(contactNameColumn));
        Log.v("WHATSAPP", c.getString(contactNameColumn)+"");
    }
}
```

I'm able to identify if "John Doe" has WhatsApp or not, but I can't figure out which phone number of "John Doe" has WhatsApp (assuming the contact has multiple phone numbers). Can anybody please help me? I've already tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497072/how-to-check-if-a-contact-on-android-phone-book-has-whatsapp-enabled), but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This example extract all the WhatsApp numbers of a contact name:

```
public void getWhatsAppNumbers(String contactName) {
    Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID},
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ? AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " = ?",
            new String[]{"com.whatsapp", contactName},
            null);

    while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
        String rawContactId = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID));

        Cursor cursor2 = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DATA3},
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? ",
                new String[]{"vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.profile", rawContactId},
                null);

        while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
            String phoneNumber = cursor2.getString(0);

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber))
                continue;

            if (phoneNumber.startsWith("Message "))
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("Message ", "");

            Log.d("whatsapp", String.format("%s - %s", contactName, phoneNumber));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked for me. Just a small correction. I didn't find any white space after "Message". So, I simply used: phoneNumber.replace("Message", "").

Comment: sir @mattia Maestrini can you suggest a way for my currently developing android application in which i register user using his phone number(number he enters,may not be device phone number).I want to get the application names(like whatsapp,paytm etc) that are using this phone number.so that i can send the linked application name along with the phone number to server. i posted this question in https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9vi48l/get_name_of_the_applications_linked_to_a_phone/